# May PDO method rowCount() return int 0 for an insert process without being caught just like in update process?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

May `PDO` method `rowCount()` return int `0` for an insert process without being caught just like in update process?

I set `PDO` error mode to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`. For a single row update process, if id does not exist in MySQL InnoDB table, then `rowCount()` returns `0` so I understand that it was not updated.

1. Is this scenario possible for an `INSERT` process? (a single row needs to be inserted, no error was caught however `rowCount()` returns int `0`)
2. If yes, can you say me a test scenario?

I think that `INSERT` will catch an error or `rowCount()` just will return int `1`.

Comment: q1: `INSERT IGNORE ...` ?

Comment: thanks @Dormilich, I didn't know IGNORE before. let the IGNORE be out of scope since it's kind of an error suppressor. Thanks again for a new knowledge for me. regards.